# Are taxes payable on bounties offered by governments?

Tags: united-states, taxes, government

Say the police is offering 1 million US dollars for information leading to a capture of a notorious criminal. Say you provide this information to the police, and they have to pay you 1 million of taxpayer money. Do you pay taxes on the amount received from the government?

Comment: Added country tag assuming the _recipient_ is also a US taxpayer.

Comment: Which country’s taxes are you asking about? Your profile says “Spain.”

Comment: Let’s consider US the case. But I am curious as to what the case is in other countries too, if you have perspectives.